# Linker errors while using VS-C++ 2010 Express edition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

Im a C++ and VS noob. Im trying to learn the CS 106b course(**Link to course [page](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/)**) by Stanford for programming using C++. However, Im running into a few issues as I try to setup the startup code.
For instance, the following code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include "graphics.h"
using namespace std;


int main(){
    initGraphics();
    setColor("BLUE");
    fillRect(50,50,300,150);
    setFont("Times New Roman");
    setColor("WHITE");
    drawString("Hello World Graphically!!",60,140);

    return 0;
}
```

compiles successfully, but throws the following linker errors.

```
        1>------ Build started: Project: HellowWorld, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
    1>Hello.obj : error LNK2005: _main already defined in GraphicsHelloWorld.obj
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(startup.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' specification
    1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
    .......
width@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (__imp_?width@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(pcgraphics.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (__imp_?width@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gtypes.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (__imp_?width@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Lock(void)" (__imp_?_Lock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Lock(void)" (__imp_?_Lock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(pcgraphics.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Lock(void)" (__imp_?_Lock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gtypes.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Lock(void)" (__imp_?_Lock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Unlock(void)" (__imp_?_Unlock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Unlock(void)" (__imp_?_Unlock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(pcgraphics.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Unlock(void)" (__imp_?_Unlock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gtypes.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Unlock(void)" (__imp_?_Unlock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_istringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void)" (__imp_??_D?$basic_istringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEXXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(strlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_istringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void)" (__imp_??_D?$basic_istringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEXXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator>><char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char &)" (__imp_??$?5DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@AAD@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_istringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_istringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (__imp_??0?$basic_istringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@1@H@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(strlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_istringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_istringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (__imp_??0?$basic_istringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@1@H@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::operator+<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,char const *)" (__imp_??$?HDU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@ABV10@PBD@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gtypes.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::operator+<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,char const *)" (__imp_??$?HDU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@ABV10@PBD@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(strlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::operator+<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,char const *)" (__imp_??$?HDU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@ABV10@PBD@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::substr(unsigned int,unsigned int)const " (__imp_?substr@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBE?AV12@II@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(strlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::substr(unsigned int,unsigned int)const " (__imp_?substr@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBE?AV12@II@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: char & __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned int)" (__imp_??A?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAADI@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(pcgraphics.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: char & __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned int)" (__imp_??A?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAADI@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(strlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: char & __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned int)" (__imp_??A?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAADI@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator==<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,char const *)" (__imp_??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@PBD@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void)" (__imp_??_D?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEXXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gtypes.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void)" (__imp_??_D?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEXXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(strlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void)" (__imp_??_D?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEXXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::str(void)const " (__imp_?str@?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@XZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gtypes.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::str(void)const " (__imp_?str@?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@XZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(strlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::str(void)const " (__imp_?str@?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@XZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct std::_Smanip<int> __cdecl std::setw(int)" (__imp_?setw@std@@YA?AU?$_Smanip@H@1@H@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int)" (__imp_??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@H@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gtypes.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int)" (__imp_??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@H@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(strlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int)" (__imp_??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@H@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char)" (__imp_??Y?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAAV01@D@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: unsigned int __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::length(void)const " (__imp_?length@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEIXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(pcgraphics.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: unsigned int __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::length(void)const " (__imp_?length@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEIXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(strlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: unsigned int __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::length(void)const " (__imp_?length@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEIXZ)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator<<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??$?MDU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@0@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gwindow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator==<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@0@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(pcgraphics.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::operator=(char const *)" (__imp_??4?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAAV01@PBD@Z)
    1>StanfordCPPLib.lib(gtypes.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::operator+<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??$?HDU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@ABV10@0@Z)
1>D:\C++Projects\HellowWorld\Release\HellowWorld.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 28 unresolved externals
```

By the way I have stored the path to the external StanfordCPPLib.lib by editing the path through `Project->Properties->Linker->Additional Dependencies->D:\C++Projects\HellowWorld\HellowWorld\StanfordCPPLib.cpp` and added the Additional header files through `Project->Properties->C/C++->Additional Include Directories->C:\Users\Vivek\Downloads\Assignment1-vs2008\StanfordCPPLib\include`
Both the folders are present in their location. Any tips on what Im doing wrong here would be helpful!

Comment: Please link the course page where you got the code so we're all sure we have the same version of all the files and the instructions.

Comment: @Kevin: Added link to course page!

Comment: Are you sure you've set the Linker->Additional Dependencies correctly? You seem to have given it a .cpp file

Comment: You are linking a .lib file (probably named graphics.lib) that was built with an older version of Visual Studio.  You'll need to get your hands on the source code for this library so you can rebuild it.  Or visit the Borland Museum to get a copy of Turbo C.

Comment: @Jonathon, I did try to correct that but no use , so I tried it on VS 2008, yet the errors persist, I now get `
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'StanfordCPPLib.lib'` error. despite mentioning the library in Linker->input->Additional Dependencies. And when I mention the entire path , I get a load of unresolved externals,116 to be precise, any idea where I could be going wrong?

Comment: @HansPassant: Tried installinng VS 2008 and doing what Ive mentioned in the above comment.. Any help from your side?

Comment: Have you added the path to the lib in: 
Linker->General->Additional library directory
?

Comment: @Giel :Yes, it was already added it points to the absolute path of the lib of the form `D:\C++Projects\StanfordCPPLib.lib`,doesnt work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two files containing definition of main() Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/646559/), [C++ Newbie: Having all sorts of problems linking](http://stackoverflow.com/q/512804/)

Comment: If you are using youtube edition of the course it uses only visual studio 2005.Instructions to set it up is here :  https://see.stanford.edu/materials/icspacs106b/h05p-usingvisualstudio.pdf